# how to make slidebar in react native?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to make a music app by react-native.  and I'm trying to make sound volume slide bar.  and I just could not find any code source how to make one.  It would be great if any one know how to make one. I wanna make something similar that I attached image in below.

[image: slidebar]

Comment: have you tried this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html

Comment: I did not know this is actually slidebar lol thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The component you are looking for is called [Slider](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html) in react native. It is provided by react-native library. You can import it and start using like this:

```
import { Slider } from 'react-native'
```